# Как правильно узнать хэш тела письма bh= при генерации DKIM подписи?

Tags: хеширование, base64, dkim

Вот моя smtp сессия после команды DATA:

```
DATA
From: "test" <info@example.com>
Subject: test

test
.
```

И вот что выдаёт мой MTA при генерации dkim:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=post; d=example.com;
 h=From:Subject;
 bh=g3zLYH4xKxcPrHOD18z9YfpQcnk/GaJedfustWU5uGs=;
 b=USJXOt1EbdXJ+jI6qulISpJxLOGHyjcarX+3Has4BrDSl6VH2RVxBBiy/CiCWjVEzZEj6sNr10sS
   B/YWt9EIWbzF7GLw1hUmvKLtTovmck+n1bqqVl6LJMRgKfxqegUUHaJ6eYdnjBZwAf4r00jKe2ab
   78GRg4luPCvmfhgw01k=
```

А когда я пытаюсь самостоятельно сделать bh= через сервисы (на https://crypt-online.ru/crypts/sha256/ кодирую test и получаю 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08, а после вставляю в https://8gwifi.org/base64Hex.jsp (вкладка "Hex to Base64")), то получаю n4bQgYhMfWWaL+qgxVrQFaO/TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg= вместо g3zLYH4xKxcPrHOD18z9YfpQcnk/GaJedfustWU5uGs=
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: В [RFC 6376, Section 3.4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.4.4) написано, что для relaxed-алгоритма нужно добавить в конец тела символы CRLF при их отсутствии (возврат каретки и перевод строки). Когда вы их добавите, у вас получится хэш `837ccb607e312b170fac7383d7ccfd61fa5072793f19a25e75fbacb56539b86b`, который в base64-представлении даст правильный результат

Comment: Причём на показанном вами сервисе посчитать такой хэш невозможно, потому что он не позволяет ввести символ возврата каретки